# close a view in eclipse rcp

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am using eclipse RCP to develop my application.

I have a view with table on it. on double click on a record from that table, it open a new view for that record to edit and there would be more than one view if I clicked more than one record in that table for each record.  however when I delete a record from parent view (where I have table) then it should delete the view which is opened for edit of that record.

how can I close the view if I delete a record from the table on parent view.

Any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used this to hide a view.

```
        IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
                .getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
        page.hideView(page.findView(View.ID));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
page.findView(<<some viewId which i assigned while opening that view>>) return null even though I opened the view with a view id (through method showView (id, uniqueId). and what if there are more than one view (like if parent view has table of record of person, and if I click more than one record to see details of more than one person), how would the eclipse context identify that I am deleting person A and it needs to close the window showing person A.

Comment: You need to create the View.ID dynamically for each record, and keep track of the View.IDs you've created.

Comment: when you say create View.ID dynamically, did you mean using any eclipse rcp API (or creating random id and store that in some collection object)
Thanks.!

Comment: Create ID and store in a Collection object.  Doesn't have to be random.

Comment: Hi, I wrote something like this :
  IWorkbenchPage page = MorpheusHandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(getEvent()).getActivePage();
  IViewReference[] viewReferences = page.getViewReferences();
  for(IViewReference ivr : viewReferences){
//within loop check for the id and hide that id else continue with the loop
      }